# JSX inside Accordion content in Native Base (React Native)

Tags: react-native, accordion, native-base

Is possible to have JSX code inside the Accordion content in native base?

```
class MyAccount extends React.Component {
    render() {

      const creditCardContent = (
          <Form>
            <Item floatingLabel>
              <Label>Name on Card</Label>
              <Input />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel>
              <Label>Card Number</Label>
              <Input />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel>
              <Label>CVC</Label>
              <Input />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel>
              <Label>Zip Code</Label>
              <Input />
            </Item>
          </Form>
      );
      const dataMenus = [
        { title: "Credit Card", content: creditCardContent },
        { title: "Bank Account (for ACH payments)", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
        { title: "Recurring Payment", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
      ];

      return (
        <Container>
          <Content padder>
            <ScrollView>
              <Accordion dataArray={dataMenus} expanded={0}/>
            </ScrollView>
          </Content>
        </Container>
      );
    }
}
```

The result is not showing the Credit Card content (image below)
[image]

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or it is not possible to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember you can do it with the `renderContent` property where you can define how it should be rendered. You can pass it as a constant or as a `renderContent = (item) => { ... }`.

But what you are doing right now is supplying the dataArray with React.Element and then bunch of strings which it can't render.

Comment: Thank you! It works, I just receive the following warning: VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.